# Is it possible to add an array of JLabel that each element have a backgroudn color inside a JLabel

Tags: java

this is my sample code i want to put the hpBar inside hpDetails so when the player is damaged/heal it is easy, and more efficient to change the status. but when i put inside the hpBar it doesnt show the hpBar it just leave the space. i really need to know if its possible to do this.

this.hpDetails = new JLabel(" ");

```
 this.hpDetails.setOpaque(true);

 this.hpBar=new JLabel[5];

 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

     this.hpBar[i] = new JLabel("   ");

     this.hpBar[i].setOpaque(true);

     this.hpBar[i].setBackground(Color.RED);

     this.hpDetails.setText(hpDetails.getText() + this.hpBar[i]);

 } 
 this.add(this.hpDetails);
```

Comment: Are you asking is a `JLabel` can contain other `JLabel`s ?

Comment: yes but the other JLabel is an array and each element has have a background color

Comment: hpBar is an array of JLabel that each element background color is red, and i want to put th hpBar inside the hpDetails which a normal JLabel

Answer (score 1):

No. A `JLabel` cannot have child `JLabel`s (or indeed an array with multiple children). You need to look at a layout manager that allows you to layout multiple `JLabel`s one after in a row.

You would normally create a `JPanel`, give it a `FlowLayout` (the default) and add all the `JLabel`s to the panel.
The other approach would be to use a "real" progress bar instead of trying to DIY.

Comment: ohhh i seee thanks thanks i guess i really have no choice but to all of it xD. Thanks for answering!!